# Accessing an specific atribute pair in a json object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, object

I need to access temperature and append it to my page If these are all objects then I suppose I cant use an index since the order doesnt matter, which is throwing me off.

```
{
"response": {
"version": "0.1",
"termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
"features": {
  "conditions": 1
 }
},
"current_observation": {
"image": {
  "url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
  "title": "Weather Underground",
  "link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
},
"display_location": {
  "full": "Toms River, NJ",
  "city": "Toms River"

},
"observation_location": {
  "full": "Stonehedge, Toms River, New Jersey",
  "city": "Stonehedge, Toms River",
  "state": "New Jersey",
  "country": "US"

},
"estimated": {},
"station_id": "KNJTOMSR5",
"observation_time": "Last Updated on April 11, 10:56 PM EDT",
"observation_time_rfc822": "Fri, 11 Apr 2014 22:56:39 -0400",
"observation_epoch": "1397271399",
"local_time_rfc822": "Fri, 11 Apr 2014 22:56:40 -0400",
"local_epoch": "1397271400",
"local_tz_short": "EDT",
"local_tz_long": "America/New_York",
"local_tz_offset": "-0400",
"weather": "Clear",
**"temperature_string": "59.6 F (15.3 C)"**

 }
}
```

My javascript right now is plainly this since I havent figured out how to access this item yet

```
$(function() {
$("#getzip").submit(function() {
var zip_data =$(this).serialize();
    $.getJSON("get_weather.php",null, function(data); {
```

I need to append this to the dom of my page, I think it shouldlook something like this?

```
   (#output).append(data.temperature_string);
```

Comment: Your JSON looks incomplete, but try `zip_data.temperature_string`.  If it's an array, loop through the array with `zip_data[i].temperature_string`

Comment: I only took part of the json since its a huge file, I just need to access this one instance of temp if that helps

Comment: See if this fiddle helps http://jsfiddle.net/mwr58/1/- it looks like you may want `<YOUR OBJECT>.current_observation.temperature_string`

Comment: There is no array in this data, just a list of objects nested in each other, I started from the top and only pasted in up to the value I needed

@Chase I'll check that out.

Actually the link is dead

Comment: @CoreyBuchillon - It was trying to include the hyphen: try  jsfiddle.net/mwr58/1/

Answer (score 1):

To get json object into javascript.

Use like this.

**In Php**

```
 $json ='{"temperature":"36 c"}';
```

**In Javascript**

```
$.post("get_weather.php",null, function(data){
 var temperature = data.temperature; // here you'll get temperature from json into variable
 console.log(temperature);
           },"json");
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

console.log(data["temperature_string"]) should access to that data.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I need to access it and append it to the DOM of my page

So if I can do something like (#output).append(data["temperature_string"]);

That would solve my issue